Access the content of a blob URL
I am trying to get access to the binary data stored in a blob URL within Firefox.
The URL is in the format blob:https://basedomain.com/blob-url.
I am on page https://basedomain.com/current-page/, where the content of the blob is embedded.
According to Convert blob URL to normal URL I should be able to access the content by performing an AJAX request.
This is my attempt in playwright-python:
page.evaluate(
    """uri => {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var recoveredBlob = xhr.response;
        var reader = new FileReader;
        reader.onload = function() {
            var blobAsDataUrl = reader.result;
            window.location = blobAsDataUrl;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(recoveredBlob);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', uri);
    xhr.send();
    }
    """, blob_url))

The issue is that this does not return anything. If I inspect the browser-console log, I get a Security Error: Content at https://basedomain.com/current-page/ may not load data from blob://basedomain.com/blob-url.
How do I access the content of this blob?
Is there an internal playwright feature to achieve this, or can the JavaScript access restriction be circumvented?

Can you share a [mcve] with full code and an example page? Thanks.

I think you misunderstand blob URL's ... what is uri/blob_url in that code, where does it come from?

@JaromandaX I've sourced it from the page html, where it is specified as the src for a <video>

are you trying to get the direct video url from a blob? you should look at the network tab for that, look for mp4/m3u links

@GTK I tried, but sadly this one is not based on the m3u8 playlist format.

can you provide the site link?

Sure. This is a video of a recent starship launch: https://www.instagram.com/reel/C5XLQc5pkx6/

@ValentinMetz you can see .mp4 urls in the network tab, but the audio and video are separate tracks, the full video url is available inside a this script: //body/script[contains(text(), 'video_versions')]. video_versions contains urls for different video resoutions

@GTK Huge thanks, this really was what I needed. The issue was not finding the relevant script, but getting the relevant script into context in the first place.
Depending on what page you access first with playwright, the script might not be contained in the page html if you navigate to by using clicks.
For some reason inspect element in Firefox also only contains the script with the video source after a page reload, even if the video plays already.

@ValentinMetz if you still need help, I suggest you ask a new question with more specific details
